# input type="datetime-local" em uma mat-table - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Estou usando um input type="datetime-local" dentro de uma mat-table em Angular. Porém os inputs não estão sendo populados conforme esperado. Quando tenho apenas um registro na tabela, está fazendo corretamente, porém quando tenho mais valores, nenhum input é populado.

Segue abaixo o código:

HTML

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceBudgetProduct">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="ApplicationDate">
                       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Agendar para </th>
                              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                  <mat-form-field id="application-date-column" appearance="outline">
                                           <input type="datetime-local" matInput formControlName="ApplicationDate" [(ngModel)]="element.ApplicationDate">
                                  </mat-form-field>
                              </td>
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsBudgetProduct"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsBudgetProduct;" class="hover-element-row"></tr>
    
</table>
```

no TS estou populando a tabela com os dados que eu trago do backend via API:

```
this.dataSourceBudgetProduct = new MatTableDataSource(response);
```

O formato retornado para este campo é:

```
ApplicationDate: "2022-10-12T08:30:00"
```

O que posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Você esta modificando o valor do input no `component.ts` ou algo assim? esse erro esta relacionado ao ciclo de vida do componente. pode compartilhar o seu código do component.ts? para que eu possa ajudar precisarei de mais informações

Comment: Na verdade este erro não está aparecendo mais Estáquio, era um erro de uma forma anterior em que estava fazendo onde eu estava modificando realmente o valor pelo component.ts... Neste caso não recebo nenhum erro, só quando tenho mais de um registro na tabela os inputs não são preenchidos.

Comment: de todo modo se puder compartilhar mais informações sobre o novo problema. se entendi direito você esta com esse input em uma tabela? certo. se esse é o caso será necessário modificar o formGroup e colocar um formArray.

Comment: Isso, editei a pergunta para entender melhor. Pode me mostrar um exemplo de como fazer um formArray para o meu caso por gentileza?

Comment: Aqui está a imagem da tabela, e destacado o campo dentro dela que quero popular: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhUeUpwTQPI_yXPcae3bnL9fYDAo?e=gKVAuP

Comment: Você esta trabalhando com FormGroup? pois acabei de perceber que no meu teste quando removi o `formControlName="ApplicationDate"` funcionou normalmente. ai cheguei a duas conclusões ou você remove o `formControlName="ApplicationDate"` e trabalha somente com o `ngModel` ou você remove o uso de `ngModel` e trabalha somente com o `formControl`, `formGroup` e `formArray`.

Comment: Realmente resolveu Eustáquio, muito obrigada

Comment: De todo modo segue um blog muito bom explicando como implementar um formArray  -> [`Angular FormArray: Complete Guide`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/)

Comment: Com certeza! Vou olhar, obrigada mesmo